# Trying to run sudo apt update and I'm receiving errors

Tags: apt, updates

I left the state for a couple weeks, leaving my computer on at home with my home network and router configured so that I could ssh in whenever necessary. It worked fine, I used it remotely constantly. One day though, I go to run `sudo apt update` 
and instead of the usual update running, I get this

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.10.0-30-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Wed Aug  9 09:27:54 2017 from 24.3.15.124
sinux@*******:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for sinux:
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [2,004 B]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [2,004 B]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [2,004 B]
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release [2,004 B]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [2,004 B]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [2,004 
B]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release [2,004 B]
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require 
authentication?)
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require 
authentication?)
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release.gpg [2,004 
B]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release.gpg [2,004 B]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release.gpg
  The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1  NODATA 2
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release.gpg
  The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1  NODATA 2
Reading package lists... Done
E: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release: The 
following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1  NODATA 2
E: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release: The 
following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1  NODATA 2
```

Can any body help me figure this out? I have tried this several times in a row. What could have happened to cause this?

**EDIT**

**Perfectly good explanation in answer**

Comment: Please read the comments and answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/899009/sudo-apt-update-always-giving-clearsigned-file-isnt-valid-got-nosplit-does

Comment: I read the thread you pointed me towards. My computer is on a home network, always connected to the internet, and has worked seemlessly until today. The thread I just read concerns a school network, etc... I'm going to look into changing repositories now, but is there anything else, specific to ubuntu that could be causing this outbif the blue? I'm remotely accessing this computer, so it's obviously connected to the internet....?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I feel stupid. What had happened was my roommates back home failed to pay our internet bill while I've been on the opposite coast, so I am still able to SSH in, but my box has no internet access. So, the question and answer that @MichaelBay pointed me towards hit the nail on the head: upstream network issues. In my case, failed to pay my bill...
***Very interesting though, I never realized I could still shell in...there's gotta be a way around getting my internet cancelled then***