# Ubuntu 18.04 not updating

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

I was trying to update the ubuntu using command `sudo apt-get update`. But it shows the following error;

```
onger signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  C                                                                                                                                                             learsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authenticat                                                                                                                                                             ion?)
E: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRe                                                                                                                                                             lease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require aut                                                                                                                                                             hentication?)
E: The repository 'http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease'                                                                                                                                                              is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                                                                                             bled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                                                                             ils.
E: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/In                                                                                                                                                             Release  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require a                                                                                                                                                             uthentication?)
E: The repository 'http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InReleas                                                                                                                                                             e' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                                                                                             bled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                                                                             ils.
portal@portal-gic:/etc/apt$ clear
portal@portal-gic:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authenti                                                                                                                                                             cation?)
Get:2 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:2 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authenti                                                                                                                                                             cation?)
Get:3 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Err:3 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authenti                                                                                                                                                             cation?)
Get:4 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Err:4 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authenti                                                                                                                                                             cation?)
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                                                                             ils.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                                                                                             bled by default.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease'                                                                                                                                                              is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRel                                                                                                                                                             ease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require auth                                                                                                                                                             entication?)
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                                                                             ils.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                                                                                             bled by default.
E: The repository 'http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is no l                                                                                                                                                             onger signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  C                                                                                                                                                             learsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authenticat                                                                                                                                                             ion?)
E: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRe                                                                                                                                                             lease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require aut                                                                                                                                                             hentication?)
E: The repository 'http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease'                                                                                                                                                              is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                                                                                             bled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                                                                             ils.
E: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/In                                                                                                                                                             Release  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require a                                                                                                                                                             uthentication?)
E: The repository 'http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InReleas                                                                                                                                                             e' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                                                                                             bled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                                                                             ils.
```

could you please help me to solve this issue? thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to change a repository and re-try?

Comment: I don't know how to change a repository and re-try. Could you please guide me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo apt update always giving Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899009/sudo-apt-update-always-giving-clearsigned-file-isnt-valid-got-nosplit-does)

Comment: You can search "Software & Updates", there from "Download from" you can change repository.

Comment: Sorry this answer not working for my case. I already tried with more then two networks to update. It is not working