# I have the following error when running sudo apt-get update, kindly assist Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT'

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, update-manager, repository

```
Get:16 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [9,890 B]     
Err:16 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease               
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:17 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease          
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

this happens on a fully updated Ubuntu 20.04 where the normal system update commands ran OK yesterday

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu? It is saying that the Microsoft entry in your sources list is causing the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo apt update always giving Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899009/sudo-apt-update-always-giving-clearsigned-file-isnt-valid-got-nosplit-does)

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the identical Microsoft URLs trying `apt update` on Linux Mint 20.2 Uma.

Comment: I also have same problem ... on Ubuntu 20.04 ... for now until this package gets fixed upstream I commented it out  however I MUST remove comment later ( tomorrow ) so my box gets updates for vscode  ... `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list`  and then comment out the only active line in that file ... btw this was fine yesterday  ... no none of the suggestions helped as referenced in link in above comment

Comment: see the microsoft github vscode ticket on this problem          https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134097

Comment: It tells you it can’t connect securely, so in the future that means it’s a sources.list bad address error, usually because the key / domain were changed.

Answer (score 1):

The repo has recently changed, you just need to change "vscode" to "code" in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list or whatever it's called on yours.

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/e7647291206dbe540c0d5121889b4f9f9c9d43f7/resources/linux/debian/postinst.template#L43-L55