# sudo apt-get update failed on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: boot

I having trouble with running command: `sudo apt-get update`
I have below errors. Do you have any ideas and suggestions, please? Thank you!

```
Err:2 http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:3 http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:4 http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:6 http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/impish/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/impish-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/impish-backports/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/impish-security/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I switch to a closer Ubuntu mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682532/how-do-i-switch-to-a-closer-ubuntu-mirror)

Comment: ... Or try again later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo apt update always giving Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899009/sudo-apt-update-always-giving-clearsigned-file-isnt-valid-got-nosplit-does)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Edit netplan File**

```
sudo vi /etc/netplan50-cloud-init.yaml
```

**2. Add Nameserver Google / Cloudflare or any, on nameserver**

```
network:
    ethernets:
        [network-device]:
            ...
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 2001:4860:4860::8888
                - 2001:4860:4860::8844
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
                - 1.1.1.1
```

*notes: don’t use tab on this file, only space allowed.*

**3. Apply and Test the Network**

```
sudo netplan apply
systemd-resolve --status
```

*References: https://josuamarcelc.com/cannot-sudo-apt-update-failed-to-update-ubuntu/*

**4. After that try again**

```
sudo apt-get update
```